# online HTML editor which preserves attributes

Tags: html, editor

Are there any free online HTML editors which preserve custom attributes in the code when you're editing the text field? The ones I've tested remove them beyond W3C standards (list below, will add to post based on suggestions).

**EDIT:** The idea is to have the changes I make to the output be reflected in the text fields of each HTML tag, then copy the changed HTML back out again. More advanced playgrounds like Codepen/JSFiddle unfortunately don't allow editing of the output, just the code.

https://htmlg.com/html-editor

https://html5-editor.net

https://wordtohtml.net

Example code - post in the HTML field of editor then change the text field:

```
<a id="id" class="class" first="FIRST" last="LAST">
This link has information outside of the conventional attributes.
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these: 
 - https://jsfiddle.net/
 - https://codepen.io

Is it what you want?

Comment: They unfortunately don't allow editing of the output; already did some research and it seems this isn't possible even with Premium on Codepen.

https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/pro-features/editable-embeds/#live-demo-0

The idea is to have the changes I make to the output be reflect in the text fields of each HTML tag, then copy the changed HTML back out again.